# jQuery touchmove stops working when removing child

Tags: javascript, jquery, gesture

I have two divs:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="child" />
</div>
```

I've created an event listener for the main element which enables the user to drag the child element around

```
map.bind('touchmove', function(f) {
                if (map.pinch) {
                    return;
                }
                f.preventDefault();
                f.originalEvent.preventDefault();
                f = f.originalEvent.touches[0];
                map.handleMoveEvent(f);
            });

map.handleMoveEvent = function(f) {
                mover.css('left', map.getX() + (f.clientX - map.lastmouse.clientX) / scaler.scale);
                mover.css('top', map.getY() + (f.clientY - map.lastmouse.clientY) / scaler.scale);
                map.lastmouse = f;
                map.moverMoved();
        }

map.moverMoved = function() {

            if (map.getX() > 0) {
                map.tileX--;
                mover.moveX(-TILE_WIDTH);
                map.find(".child").moveX(TILE_WIDTH);
                map.updateVisibleTiles();
            }
            if (map.getX() < -TILE_WIDTH) {
                map.tileX++;
                mover.moveX(TILE_WIDTH);
                map.find(".child").moveX(-TILE_WIDTH);
                map.updateVisibleTiles();
            }
            if (map.getY() > 0) {
                map.tileY--;
                mover.moveY(-TILE_HEIGHT);
                map.find(".child").moveY(TILE_HEIGHT);
                map.updateVisibleTiles();
            }
            if (map.getY() < -TILE_HEIGHT) {
                map.tileY++;
                mover.moveY(TILE_HEIGHT);
                map.find(".child").moveY(-TILE_HEIGHT);
                map.updateVisibleTiles();
            }

            $('#console').html(map.tileX + " " + map.tileY);
            //$('#console').html(map.getX() + " " + map.getY());
        };

map.updateVisibleTiles = function() {
                mover.find(".child").remove();
                for (x = Math.max(map.tileX - tiledistance, 0); x <= Math.min(map.tileX + tiledistance, map.getTileCount() - 1); x++) {
                    for (y = Math.max(map.tileY - tiledistance, 0); y <= Math.min(map.tileY + tiledistance, map.getTileCount() - 1); y++) {
                        var child = $(document.createElement('div'));
                        child.width(TILE_WIDTH);
                        child.height(TILE_HEIGHT);
                        var farbe = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                        child.css("background-color", farbe);
                        child.css('position', 'absolute');
                        child.addClass('child');
                        child.css('left', (x - map.tileX) * TILE_WIDTH);
                        child.css('top', (y - map.tileY) * TILE_HEIGHT);
                        mover.append(child);
                    }
                }
            }
```

In some situations i have to exchange the child while dragging

```
$('.main').find(".child").remove();
```

but after removing the touchmove does not fire anymore. It only happens when i start the touchmove by tapping on the child element... The problem is obvios to me, but what's the solution?

Comment: Is `$('main')` supposed to be `$('.main')`? Also Your bind function isn't closed. What's in that function?

Comment: Maybe, maybe this will fix it: `$('.child').bind('touchstart',function(e){e.originalEvent.preventDefault(); e.originalEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();});`. Now the touch-event on the child does nothing, so the `touchmove` comes from the `.main` directly. Although it's also possible that this breaks your code completely and removes any dragsupport:D I'm quite serious though, please let me know if it works

Comment: @myfunkyside nice idea but now the event is not propagated to main

Comment: @wutzebaer - okay yeah, that's what I was afraid of, I was hoping it would still work because it has it's own event-listener, but it doesn't work like that aperantly

Comment: @wutzebaer - I do see a possible error in your code: `f.originalEvent.preventDefault();` should be `f.preventDefault();`. I made the mistake of copying it into my previous comment, but if I recall the `originalEvent` should only be used for the `touches`

Answer (score 1):

`$().remove()` removes the dom element and it's event listeners. Use `$().detach()` to preserve event listeners.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

Comment: Looking back through your code, you're not removing elements then re-inserting them, You're removing elements then RE-CREATING THEM. If you're creating new elements, then you need to add event listeners to them.

Comment: they never got event listeners, only map has the event listener

Answer (score 1):

i just created an invisible overlay which handles the event, this seems to work:

```
var toch = $(document.createElement('div'));
toch.css('position', 'absolute');
toch.css('width', '100%');
toch.css('height', '100%');
map.append(toch);

toch.bind('touchmove', function(f) {})
```